# Comparing modification dates of files within 2 directories

Tags: perl

So I've come up with a little project for myself to help learn Perl, something that I can actually use. The idea is to compare a list of files modification dates within 2 directories. 1 From an FTP, and 1 on my local and upload the ones from local if they are newer(this part can be handled later). I've created separate scripts(I plan on combining them, just tinkering at the moment), one for reading directory from the FTP and grabbing the files. The other compares the list of files in 2 directories (file lists are located in an array), which is where the problem comes. I can get it to compare two directories. I can't seem to workout how to get it to compare files of the same name. If there are files that exist in only one of the directories, it will compare that file to another file in the same array position.

This could be handled quite easily (I say easily, but I'm not sure) with an if statement, but can't comprehend which parameters will do it.

What I have so far:

```
 opendir(IMD, "/TRAINING/Perl") || die("Cannot open directory"); 
        @thefiles= readdir(IMD); 
        opendir(IMD2, "/TRAINING/Perl2") || die("Cannot open directory"); 
        @thefiles2= readdir(IMD2)

    foreach my $file (@thefiles) {
     #  if ($file != @thefiles2[$counter]){
        if (compare($file, @thefiles2[$counter]) == 0){
            print $file, " Matches ";
            print @thefiles2[$counter], "\n";   
            $counter++;
        }

     #  elsif ($file == @thefiles2[$counter]){  
        elsif (compare($file, @thefiles2[$counter]) != 0){
            print $file, " ";
            print "Does not match";
            print @thefiles2[$counter], "\n";
            $counter++; 
        }
    }
```

At the moment I'm just comparing names of files in the same array position, until I can get it working properly, then will change it to use dates. Already had it using -M but was doing the same thing it's doing now. I realise this is far from what I need, and really need any pointers, especially since my programming in general is pretty noobish.

Essentially what I want it to do,

```
If ($file1 !exists in $dir2){
    Print "not exists"
}
If ($file1 exists in $dir2){
    Compare its date with $file2 in $dir2 and print newer/older
}
```

If I can get this working for now, then I can slowly modify it to what I want it to do.

Thanks for any assistance you guys can offer me.

Comment: You should really try to make your question more brief and to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is you have to use relative paths, not absolute paths. Otherwise you'll never get a match.  So, if the "base" folder is, say, /Folder then the file /Folder/subfolder/file should be represented as subfolder/file.

The next step is to load up two hashes, one with files from the first location, the other with the files from the second location.  Use the relative paths as the keys, and then the values can be other information that you can use to gauge "equality."  Modification time, or file size, or MD5... Whatever you want.

Then, you step through all the keys in the first hash, checking each in the second hash.  If it doesn't exist, then the file isn't in the second location (new file?).  If it does exist, then you can check the associated values for "equality" to see if the file was updated/changed.  When you find a match, delete the key from the second hash.  Then, what's left in the second hash are the files that don't exist in the first location (deleted files?).

This is tricky stuff, though.  If you try to mirror, you have to be cognizant of folders.  If you're adding files, you have to do the folders first in sorted order... E.g. So that you mkdir subfolder/ before trying to make subfolder/subfolder2/.

Conversely, if you're trying to remove stuff, you have to reverse the above... Remove the files first, then remove the folders in descending sort order... e.g. Remove subfolder/subfolder2/ before trying to rmdir subfolder/.

Finally, you also have to be able to affect the modification time of files on the receiving end.  When you FTP a file to a server, it will get the current time.  Which means if you use MTIME as a means of telling if a file is new, it will never compare equal again.  Not all FTP servers have means of updating file times.

Good luck.  In the end, things like rsync are a far better solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot rely on assumption that **readdir** returns ordered list. So its wrong to compare just using indexes, even if you sort you cannt rely since there may be file which does not exists in other directory. Also, your code is not working with subdirectories. Options you can use:

- Use a Perl modules, e.g. [File::DirWalk](http://search.cpan.org/~jensl/File-DirWalk-0.4/lib/File/DirWalk.pm). This allows to work with subdirectoies and you can make hash which contains file paths and their modification time returned by **stat**
- Use unix utilities such BSD [mtree(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mtree&sektion=8)